# Override of method in swift library does not work

Tags: swift3, realm

I am using a library "RealmSearchViewController" and overriding a method. But the method in the invoking view controller is not exercise. Instead the code in the library is executed which prints out a message "You need to implement searchViewController(controller:,cellForObject object:,atIndexPath indexPath:)". My code is shown below (I took out some extraneous code)

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import RealmSearchViewController

class SearchController: RealmSearchViewController {




    override func searchViewController(_ controller: RealmSearchViewController, cellForObject object: Object, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let record = object as? WorkorderRecord
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! WorkorderCell
....
    return cell
}
```

Here is the prototype from the library:

```
    open func searchViewController(_ controller: RealmSearchViewController, cellForObject object: Object, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    print("You need to implement searchViewController(controller:,cellForObject object:,atIndexPath indexPath:)")

    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Comment: are you using your controller or the libraries controller directly? Can you show code of controller class implementation

Comment: My controller is sub-classed from RealmSearchViewController. I have added the beginning code in the edited question.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is double check you are actually using `SearchController` in your storyboard or nib.

Comment: That was it!!! I had accidentally selected RealmSearchViewController  in the storyboard. Thank you so much. If you put your suggestion as an answer for my question I will close the question and give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check you are actually using `SearchController` in your storyboard or nib